# Combining two rows to a single row

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm getting following output from a query shown in figure 01. Every employee has two records showing their work locations together with effective dates. Current flag shows the current record denoted by 'Y'. 
Now I want to convert this output to the following format shown in figure 02. Here an employee has a single row. It shows employee's current record and transfer date, previous location and new location.

[image: Figure 01]

[image: Figure 02]

Can you show me how to do this please?

Comment: excatly two locations, or "one and more"?

Comment: yep. exactly two locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
--PREVIOUSRESULT will be your existing result.

SELECT A.EMPLOYEENO, A.NAME, A.CURRENTFLAG, 
   (SELECT B.LOCATION FROM PREVIOUSRESULT B
    WHERE B.EMPLOYEENO = A.EMPLOYEENO AND B.CURRENTFLAG IS NULL) AS FROMVALUE, 
    A.Location AS ToValue, A.TRANSFERDATE AS EFFECTIVEDATE 
 FROM PREVIOUSRESULT A 
 WHERE A.CURRENTFLAG = 'Y'
```

[--Result](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab54d/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just one more answer:

```
select a.empno, a.ename, a.cflag, 
(select b.location from empdetails b where b.empno=a.empno and b.cflag is null) "From",
a.location "To", a.transfer_date from empdetails a where a.cflag is not null;
```

Check this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ffc4/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Employee No]
, [Name]
, MAX([Current Flag]) as [Current Flag]
, CASE WHEN [Current Flag] IS NULL THEN LOCATION ELSE NULL END AS [FROM]
, CASE WHEN [Current Flag] = 'Y' THEN LOCATION ELSE NULL END AS [TO]
, CASE WHEN [Current Flag] = 'Y' THEN [TRANSFER DATE] ELSE NULL END AS [EFFECTIVE DATE]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [Employee No]
, [Name]
, CASE WHEN [Current Flag] IS NULL THEN LOCATION ELSE NULL END
, CASE WHEN [Current Flag] = 'Y' THEN LOCATION ELSE NULL END
, CASE WHEN [Current Flag] = 'Y' THEN [TRANSFER DATE] ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: Thanks. but there are issues in the output. Either from_date or to_date is null always!

Answer (score 0):

Given strictly two records for each employee, I would expect this one to be faster - only one table scan, no nested loop joins.

```
select 
empno, 
ename, 
max(cflag) cflag, 
max(location) keep(dense_rank first order by transfer_date) "from",
max(location) keep(dense_rank last  order by transfer_date) "to",
max(transfer_date) transfer_date
from empdetails
group by empno, ename;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ffc4/7)